# Could there be any issues with doing a double NSUTF8StringEncoding on a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsstringencoding

So I am making a POST call to my server with the following code:

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
NSString *POSTencoded = [POSTdata stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
NSData *postData = [POSTencoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

The function `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:` automatically uses UTF-8 encoding on my string, according to Apple's documentation. I am not sure if it's a lossy conversion or not though.

Then on the next line I encode the data again, making sure I set `allowLossyConversion:` to `YES`.

Questions:

1. Does `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:` have lossy conversion set to `YES` or `NO`?
2. Does double-encoding with UTF8 have the potential to convert some of my characters in unforeseen ways?